# OpenVPN setting up own server 2 errors

Tags: networking, server, ssh, vpn, openvpn

I followed a guide on creating your own VPN using OpenVPN and only encountered two errors from [openVPN guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-16-04). I think my VPN is created but I thought this would be useful since I am in Libraries using open WiFi.

When I ran `sudo ufw allow OpenSSH` I got an error message: **ERROR: Could not find a profile matching 'OpenSSH'**

Another issue I encounter was after I ran `sftp tim@openvpn_server_ip:client-configs/files/client1.ovpn ~/` I received the message **ssh: Could not resolve hostname openvpnserverip: Name or service not known
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer**

Thanks for any help in advance! I tried running the second command again and it wouldn't terminate so I had to ctrl + c it myself

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have encountered the same ERROR:

```
ERROR: Could not find a profile matching 'OpenSSH'
```

So what I did was to run:

```bash
sudo apt-get install ssh
```

After installing, I ran:

```
cd ~/openvpn-ca
sudo ufw allow OpenSSH
```

And I verified it with:

```
sudo ufw status
```

I hope it will work for you too!

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sudo ufw allow OpenSSH
ERROR: Could not find a profile matching 'OpenSSH'
```

Run

```
sudo apt-get install ssh
```

and then:

```
$ sudo ufw allow OpenSSH
Rules updated
Rules updated (v6)
```

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

```
$ sudo ufw enable
Firewall is active and enabled on system startup
```

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: active
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
8080                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8080 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```